# How to set env variables for maven to run test correctly?

Tags: maven, junit, pom.xml

Is it possible to set env vars in pom.xml that junit tests uses? Netbeans can get env vars and builds project correnctly. But when i use command line (mvn clean -> mvn install), build fails due to test errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two approaches I know.

**Commandline:**

You can pass it in command line like

```
mvn -DAM_HOME=conf install
```

**Using pom :**

If `AM_HOM` is the variable and the value is `conf` ,make entry  like below.

```
<plugins>
    ...


 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
            ...
            <environmentVariables>
                <AM_HOME>conf</AM_HOME>
            </environmentVariables>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

...
<plugins>
```

Comment: so , why can't he add these lines directly to the POM.xml rather than adding them through command line

Comment: This is the same solution that i use before. System.getEnv("AM_HOME") returns null.

Comment: Sorry, error was found. Thank you for help. But i use <environmantVariables> instead

Comment: BTW, dont you know, is it possible to define some env var using previously defined var? For example:<systemPropertyVariables>
                <AM_HOME>conf</AM_HOME> <AM_HOME2>${AM_HOME}2</AM_HOME2>
            </systemPropertyVariables>

Comment: That does the trick. This is the right way to set env variables to be read later using `System.getEnv`, different to most answers to this same question around the internet that say the right way is setting a property.