# How to set env variable from within junit test case?

Tags: maven, guice, env

I followed [How to set env variables for maven to run test correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078863/how-to-set-env-variables-for-maven-to-run-test-correctly) and configured my pom like this :

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.15</version>
   <configuration>
       <systemPropertyVariables>
           <SENDGRID_USERNAME>username</SENDGRID_USERNAME>
           <SENDGRID_PASSWORD>password</SENDGRID_PASSWORD>
       </systemPropertyVariables>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

when i run `mvn test` command, it is giving the following error,

```
Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalStateException: SENDGRID_PASSWORD env variable must be set.
```

What am i doing wrong ?

When I was doing research to find the answer, I found out the following : [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) can be used set env for processes spawned with it. I dont know whether ProcessBuilder helps in my case as I am not spawning any processes. My project is maven project and i run test with mvn test command.

Can any body explains me how to set env for situations like this (i.e., maven + junit )

I am able to set the `properties` but the problem is how to set `environment variable` as my program is expecting the env variable.

Comment: That looks fine to me. How is the env variable being retrieved, System.getProperty("SENDGRID_PASSWORD") ? Have u checked that?

Comment: When i tried to retrieve in @BeforeClass method,  System.getProperty("SENDGRID_PASSWORD") returned `null`

Comment: Well that's weird, since system properties should be available already when you reach a @BeforeClass method.

Comment: @vikingsteve  you are right, I can verify env in @BeforeClass. The issue I am facing is; in my MyClassTest.java i am trying to instantiate MyClass. And one of the member of MyClass is initialized with Guice injection. This is where the exception is being throws as: `tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.778 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.a.b.c.MyClassTest
testMethod()  Time elapsed: 0.778 sec  <<< ERROR!
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.IllegalStateException: SENDGRID_PASSWORD env variable must be set`.

Comment: No worries, thanks for that info, it's outside my knowledge so I edited your question and added the `guice` tag.

Answer (score 2):

If I read the documentation correctly, the configuration to use is:

```
 <environmentVariables>
       <SENDGRID_USERNAME>username</SENDGRID_USERNAME>
       <SENDGRID_PASSWORD>password</SENDGRID_PASSWORD>
 </environmentVariables>
```

Could this be the issue?

Source: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#environmentVariables